# How do I compile OSS LINN's code under Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: c#, xcode4, xamarin, scons, upnp

I have already built up the environment using [Linn's build instructions](http://oss.linn.co.uk/trac/wiki/BuildInstructions) for mac and as the part of that I have installed Xamarin Studio 4.0.13.

I have already got the source codes but how do I compile from Xamarin?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Visual Studio solutions that can be opened in Xamarin Studio in the directories Vs2010 and Vs2008. Vs2010 contains the Windows, Mac OS X and Linux solutions and Vs2008 contains the iOS solutions.

I am assuming that you want to compile Kinsky for Mac OS X, in which case the solution file you want is KinskyDesktopMonobjc.sln.

You will need to build using scons at least once, to ensure all the auto generated source files are created, before you will be able to compile Kinsky from Xamarin Studio.